# Windows Hello PIN on domain computer is not available after creating or updating PIN

Tags: active-directory, windows-10

User had a PIN setup when our previous network admin setup Windows Hello across our AD. Our current network admin changed some GPO settings (he does not know what he changed) and now the user cannot use a PIN to sign in to their account. I assumed it needed to be recreated, so I tried the  "I forgot my PIN" link. New PIN created. Locked the screen and entered the PIN. Received the message:

"This option is currently unavailable. For now, please use a different method to sign in."

So, I went to the Ngc folder and deleted everything inside it. Same message.

Checked the GPO on the DC. Convenience PIN is enabled, everything in Windows Hello is not configured.

Went to RegEdit, changed the AllowPIN key to 0, restarted, changed back to 1, restarted. Same message.

Checked for an alternate GPO that had the Windows Hello options enabled. Found none.

Created a new user profile to see if it was an issue with the other user's profile. Same issue with the new profile.

I seem to have exhausted every resource I can find. Is there something I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

I suspected the domain trust on that workstation might be wonky, so I dropped the workstation from the domain and re-added it. 24 hours in and it seems to be working fine!